# How to loop all the functions inside a class

Tags: loops, swiftui

There is a class created that consists variables declared inside so that I can use them functions as formulas and don't need to declare variables again separately.
Trying to loop over all the functions inside a class for a variable **fr** that will be passed as array.
The output will be used to prepare a graph

`import SwiftUI

class MyDataStore: ObservableObject {

```
@Published var bitsize: Double = 0
@Published var **fr**: Double = 0
@Published var tfa: Double = 0

@Published var yp: Double = 0
@Published var pv: Double = 0
@Published var mw: Double = 0

@Published var StringID: Double = 0
@Published var StringOD: Double = 0
@Published var cssize: Double = 0
@Published var dplen: Double = 0
@Published var cslen: Double = 0

@Published var ed: Double = 0
@Published var npl: Double = 0
@Published var kpl: Double = 0
@Published var khb: Double = 0
@Published var y: Double = 0

@Published var buffer: Double = 0
@Published var Strider: Double = 0

@Published var dPMWD: Double = 0
@Published var dPPDM: Double = 0

@Published var surftype: String = ""


func dPSurface() -> Double {
    if surftype == "1" { return (0.00025) * (pow(mw, 0.8)) * (pow(fr, 1.8)) * (pow(pv, 0.2)) }
    if surftype == "2" { return (0.000096) * (pow(mw, 0.8)) * (pow(fr, 1.8)) * (pow(pv, 0.2)) }
    if surftype == "3" { return (0.000053) * (pow(mw, 0.8)) * (pow(fr, 1.8)) * (pow(pv, 0.2)) }
    else {return (0.000042) * (pow(mw, 0.8)) * (pow(fr, 1.8)) * (pow(pv, 0.2)) } }


//Velocity Formula
func VelocityString() -> Double {
    return  fr / (2.488 * pow(StringID, 2)) }
///Velocity in String
func VelocityAnnulusOpenHole() -> Double {
    return fr / (2.488 * pow(( bitsize  - StringID), 2)) }
///Velocity in Annulus: Open Hole
func VelocityAnnulusCasedHole() -> Double {
    return fr / (2.488 * pow((cssize - StringID), 2)) }
///Velocity in Annulus: Cased



//  Bingham Plastic Model  //

//Apparent Viscosity
func ApparentViscString() -> Double {
    return ( ( 6.66 * yp * StringID ) / VelocityString() ) + pv }
///Apparent Viscosity in String
func ApparentViscAnnulusOpenHole() -> Double {
    return ( ( 6.66 * yp * (bitsize - StringOD ) ) / VelocityAnnulusOpenHole() ) + pv }
///Apparent Viscosity in Annulus Open
func ApparentViscAnnulusCasedHole() -> Double {
    return ( ( 6.66 * yp * (cssize - StringID ) ) / VelocityAnnulusCasedHole() ) + pv }
///Apparent Viscosity in Annulus Open Hole

//Reynolds Number
func ReString () -> Double {
    return ( 928 * mw * VelocityString() * StringID ) / ApparentViscString() }
///Reynolds Number String: String
func ReAnnulusOpenHole () -> Double {
    return ( 928 * mw * VelocityAnnulusOpenHole() * (bitsize - StringID) ) / ApparentViscAnnulusOpenHole()}
///Reynolds Number Annulus: Open Hole:
func ReAnnulusCasedHole () -> Double {
    return ( 928 * mw * VelocityAnnulusCasedHole() * (cssize - StringOD) ) / ApparentViscAnnulusCasedHole()}
///Reynolds Number Annulus: Cased Hole:

//Moody Friction Factor
func MoodyFFString () -> Double {
    return ( pow( ( ( ed / StringID ) * 20000 ) + ( pow(10, 6) / (ReString()) ), 1/3 ) + 1 ) * 0.001375 }
///Moody Friction Factor String
func MoodyFFAnnulusOpenHole () -> Double {
    return ( pow( ( ( ed / (bitsize - StringID) ) * 20000 ) + ( pow(10, 6) / (ReAnnulusOpenHole()) ), 1/3 ) + 1 ) * 0.001375 }
///Moody Friction Factor Annulus: Open Hole
func MoodyFFAnnulusCasedHole () -> Double {
    return ( pow( ( ( ed / (cssize - StringOD) ) * 20000 ) + ( pow(10, 6) / (ReAnnulusCasedHole()) ), 1/3 ) + 1 ) * 0.001375 }
///Moody Friction Factor Annulus: Cased Hole

//Bingham Plastic Model Pressure Drop: Laminar -
func dPstringBPMlam () ->Double {
    return ( ( ( pv * VelocityString() ) / (1500 * pow(StringID, 2)) ) + ( yp / ( 225 * StringID) ) ) * dplen}
///Laminar pressure drop: String
func dPannulusOpenHoleBPMlam () ->Double {
    return ( ( ( pv * VelocityAnnulusOpenHole() ) / (1000 * pow((bitsize - StringOD), 2)) ) + ( yp / ( 200 * (bitsize - StringOD)) ) ) * (dplen - cslen) }
///Laminar pressure drop Annulus: Open Hole
func dPannulusCasedHoleBPMlam () -> Double {
    return ( ( ( pv * VelocityAnnulusCasedHole() ) / (1000 * pow((cssize - StringOD), 2)) ) + ( yp / ( 200 * (cssize - StringOD)) ) ) * cslen}
///Laminar pressure drop Annulus: Cased Hole
func dPannulusBPMlam () -> Double {
    return dPannulusOpenHoleBPMlam() + dPannulusCasedHoleBPMlam() }
///Laminar pressure drop - Annulus: Cased Hole + Open Hole
///
///
//Bingham Plastic Model Pressure Drop: Turbulent -
func dPStringBPMturb () -> Double {
    return ( MoodyFFString() * mw * pow(VelocityString(), 2) * dplen ) / (25.8 * StringID) }
///Turbulent Pressure Drop: String
func dPannulusBPMOpenHoleturb() -> Double {
    return ( MoodyFFAnnulusOpenHole() * mw * pow(VelocityAnnulusOpenHole(), 2) * (dplen-cslen) ) / ( 21.1 * (bitsize - StringOD) ) }
///Turbulent pressure drop - Annulus: Open Hole
func dPannulusBPMCasedHoleturb() -> Double {
    return ( MoodyFFAnnulusCasedHole() * mw * pow(VelocityAnnulusCasedHole(), 2) * (cslen) ) / ( 21.1 * (cssize - StringOD) ) }
///Turbulent pressure drop - Annulus: Cased Hole
func dPannulusBPMturb () -> Double {
    return dPannulusBPMOpenHoleturb() + dPannulusBPMCasedHoleturb() }
///Turbulent pressure drop - Annulus: Cased Hole + Open Hole


//Bingham Plastic Model Pressure Drop
func dPStringBPM() -> Double {
    if ReString() < 3000 { return dPstringBPMlam() }
    else { return dPStringBPMturb() } }

func dPannulusBPM() -> Double {
    if ReAnnulusOpenHole() < 3000 { return dPannulusBPMlam() }
    else { return dPStringBPMturb() } } }`
```

Comment: I don't think you can but if you are observing properly you shouldn't need to. The `View` would reload when the `@Published` is updated. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: for all the functions inside class, I want them to loop for each value of fr [50, 100, 150, 200, 250]. These functions are essentially the formulas and I want the final out of the dPStringBPM(), etc. for the all the values of fr passed

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? This sounds like a request and SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).